# How to retrieve linkedin information of other people using python and oauth 2?

Tags: python, api, oauth, linkedin-api

1) Followed the steps for keys creation on developer site of linkedin.
2) Works well to get my information using Python and oauth 2.0:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import time

url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"

consumer_key = 'my_app_key'
consumer_secret = 'my_app_secret_key'

oath_key = 'oath_key'
oath_secret = 'oath_secret_key'

consumer = oauth.Consumer(
     key=consumer_key,
     secret=consumer_secret)

token = oauth.Token(
     key=oath_key,
     secret=oath_secret)


client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(url)
print resp
print content
```

But, I want to know the information of other people, e.g. to get the info based on first_name, last_name, and company.

There seems to be good information at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api
but, cannot get through it.

What exactly is "id" value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can get public profile data of somebody if you know their public profile url or their unique member id, but you can't query on anything else.